# MacTex (texlive) - pn2pdf: command not found

Tags: mactex

My MacTex seems to be missing the "pn2pdf" executable

I searched the whole harddrive, but it only finds the corresponding documentation.
I tried `sudo tlmgr install --reinstall petri-nets` but file is still missing, although tlmgr reports petri-nets is installed. (see `tlmgr info petri-nets` below)

Any ideas?

```
package:     petri-nets
category:    Package
shortdesc:   A set TeX/LaTeX packages for drawing Petri nets.
longdesc:    Petri-nets offers a set of TeX/LaTeX packages about Petri nets and related models. Three packages are available: the first allows the user to draw Petri-nets in PostScript documents; the second defines macros related to PBC, M-nets and B(PN) models; and a third that combines the other two.
installed:   Yes
revision:    24088
sizes:       doc: 285k, run: 49k
relocatable: No
cat-date:    2014-10-15 19:06:54 +0200
cat-license: gpl
collection:  collection-pictures
```

Comment: It's a bug in TeX Live: the script is saved in the `doc` subtree instead of the `scripts` subtree.

Comment: I filed a report on the TeX Live mailing list: http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-December/037567.html

Comment: thank you for creating that bug ticket and giving me that hint. i thought it would be enough to navigate the finder to / and initiate a search for "pn2pdf". but as it shows, it wasn't.

Comment: See http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2015-December/037568.html

Comment: Thanks, for info. Thus it should be enough to do a `sudo tlmgr update --all` once tonights build is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Update available for TexLive / MacTex

For MacTex via TexLive Utility:

`TeX Live Utility` application, which is to be found in the `/Applications/TeX` directory. Open it, choose the «Update» list, then select the petri-nets package and update it (command-u, or go the menu «Action/Update selected package(s)»

*Thanks to Franck Pastor*

---

For MacTex via console:

`sudo tlmgr update --self`

`sudo tlmgr update --all`

---

Otherwise:

If you really need to do it manually:

As egreg pointed out, the `pn2pdf` file is there, but it is not executable and not in the right folder.

Steps for MacOs / MacTex:

1. make pn2pdf executable

   `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/generic/petri-nets/pn2pdf`
2. create link from `texbin` path to pn2pdf, until TexLive will include pn2pdf that is correctly placed. It may be needed to manually remove this link, once the petri-nets package provided in TexLive is updated.

   `sudo ln -s  /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/generic/petri-nets/pn2pdf /Library/TeX/texbin/pn2pdf`

Comment: Note that now that the problem is reported and solved, an easier way to update the TeXLive distribution of MacTeX would to use the TeXLive Utility application, which is to be found in the /Applications/TeX directory. Open it, choose the «Update» list, then select the petri-nets package and update it (command-u, or go the menu «Action/Update selected package(s)».